# Show a counter in loading screen (that count list items), before the list is created in the next Activity

Tags: java, android, list, size, counter

I would like to show a counter that display a `list.size()` in my loading screen (the Activity that is launched when the app is starting. The problem is that my `list` is created in the next Activity, so I have no clue on how to do that.

I know how to do it in the same Activity where my list is created but not in another.

Is there a way to link an information from an Activity to another ? or to load the 2nd activity without showing it, to create the list, count the number of items in it and show it in the 1st activity ?

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the list in ActivityOne and display the progress in ActivityOne.
Once it has been loaded you could start ActivityTwo and add your list as extra.
Your List has to contain objects which implement Parcelable. Take a look at this example.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("someArrayList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)someArrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

[More Info on Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)

Comment: Thank's for your help. The idea is perfect, you learn me something new with Parcelable. To use it seems that I have to re-write the way my list is made. It looks complicated for my skills...